# Compare two arrays and remove partially matched strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

i'm having trouble filtering an array based on partially matched content from another.

```
var arrayComplete = [
  'blue.house',
  'blue.bird',
  'blue.ocean',
  'red.chair',
  'red.curtain',
  'black.screen',
  'green.grass',
  'green.parrot'
];

var arrayToRemove = [blue, red];
```

I need to end up with an array that had elements removed based on partial string matchs:

For example, in this case, based on having the colours "blue" and "red" all elements that had "blue" and "red" on their string were removed

```
['black.screen','green.grass','green.parrot'];
```

Any tips?

I'm trying

```
let newArray = arrayComplete.filter((e) => arrayToRemove.includes(e))
```

But returns empty array. I assume because it's not matching partial strings.

Comment: Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter and to filter use includes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: What kind of trouble?

Comment: @jarmod I suspect `arrayToRemove` is a list of partial strings to match/remove.

Comment: Because i have a list of "group.name", but also have an array of "groups", so i tried to filter, but have been getting errors trying to identify partially similar strings. Like i can find and remove "blue" but not "blue.something". I've been trying to apply the include in this, but is not working as i desire, i must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go over the elements, split them at the dot and check if any of the parts are contained in the excluded elements:

```js
var arrayComplete = [
  'blue.house',
  'blue.bird',
  'blue.ocean',
  'red.chair',
  'red.curtain',
  'black.screen',
  'green.grass',
  'green.parrot'
];

var arrayToRemove = ['blue', 'red'];
const f = (arr, els) => arr.filter(it => it.split('.').every(v => !els.includes(v)))
console.log(f(arrayComplete, arrayToRemove))
```

Or if you want to avoid split, you can use a regex which tests for the appearance of the excluded word (check that it is surrounded by word boundaries with `\b`)

```js
    var arrayComplete = [
      'blue.house',
      'blue.bird',
      'blue.ocean',
      'red.chair',
      'red.curtain',
      'black.screen',
      'green.grass',
      'green.parrot'
    ];

    var arrayToRemove = ['blue', 'red'];
    const f = (arr, els) => arr.filter(it => !els.map(el => new RegExp('\\b'+el+'\\b')).some(regex => regex.test(it)))
    console.log(f(arrayComplete, arrayToRemove))
```

Comment: I was trying to solve this without using split, but could not find a solution since without it, the include returned false. I think the only other way, would be to manipulate the data itself to apply a simplier format. But solved the problem i was having, so thanks a lot !

Comment: @Lidm You don't **need** `split`; you just need to check if the entry `startsWith` any element contained in `arrayToRemove` (assuming you don't care about things like `red-ish.light`)

Comment: @Lidm Ah, check the updated answer, if you don't want to use `split()`, you can use a regex to check if the excluded word appears. `includes()` works too, but the problem is that it does not check for word boundaries, so you can run into false matches (i.e. "alfred" includes "red")

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with `Array#filter` and `String#includes` methods:

```js
const
      arrayComplete = [ 'blue.house', 'blue.bird', 'blue.ocean', 'red.chair', 'red.curtain', 'black.screen', 'green.grass', 'green.parrot' ],
      
      arrayToRemove = ['blue', 'red'],
      
      output = arrayComplete
        .filter(value => !arrayToRemove.some(st => value.includes(st)));
        
console.log( output );
```

**Alternatively .....**

If your aim was to exclude strings that start with `<color>.` where `<color>` is an element of `arrayToRemove` then you can use `String#startsWith` instead of `String#includes` as follows:

```js
const
      arrayComplete = [ 'blue.house', 'blue.bird', 'blue.ocean', 'red.chair', 'red.curtain', 'black.screen', 'green.grass', 'green.parrot', 'green.credenza' ],
      
      arrayToRemove = ['blue', 'red'],
      
      output = arrayComplete
        .filter(value => !arrayToRemove.some(st => value.startsWith(`${st}.`)));
        
console.log( output );
```

Comment: The proposed solution fails if one of the arrayComplete values is `'green.credenza'` , for example, because it includes 'red' in the suffix word.

Comment: You're quite right if you interpret the request to say *starts with*; I will include an option that uses `String#startsWith` method. Clearly, you can agree with me *based on having the colours "blue" and "red" all elements that had* does not necessarily translate to *starts with*.

Comment: But programmers need to be able to interpret imprecisely-worded requirements ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
let originalArray =  ['blue.house','blue.bird','blue.ocean','red.chair','red.curtain','black.screen','green.grass','green.parrot'];
var arrayToRemove = ['blue','red']

originalArray = originalArray.filter((e) => !(e.includes(arrayToRemove[0]) || e.includes(arrayToRemove[1] )))
console.log(originalArray)
```

this will work only if you have fixed no of items to be remove

Answer (score 0):

You could take a nested approach nd filter by looking the to unwanted strings and check if they exist, then remove this item.

```js
const
    arrayComplete = ['blue.house', 'blue.bird', 'blue.ocean', 'red.chair', 'red.curtain', 'black.screen', 'green.grass', 'green.parrot'],
    arrayToRemove = ['blue', 'red'],
    result = arrayComplete.filter(s => !arrayToRemove.some(r => s.includes(r)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using the following [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) criteria:

```
string => !arrayToRemove.some(part => string.includes(part))
```

`!array.some(...)` might be a bit confusing. There is [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), but for some reason JavaScript doesn't have `none()`.

`!array.some()` is the equivalent of the non-existent `array.none()`. For a better understanding you could see the above as:

```
// none of the `arrayToRemove` elements partially matches the string
string => arrayToRemove.none(part => string.includes(part))
// concept JavaScript   ^^^^ doesn't actually exisit
```

```js
const arrayComplete = [
  'blue.house',
  'blue.bird',
  'blue.ocean',
  'red.chair',
  'red.curtain',
  'black.screen',
  'green.grass',
  'green.parrot'
];

const arrayToRemove = ['blue', 'red'];

const filtered = arrayComplete.filter((string) => (
  !arrayToRemove.some(part => string.includes(part))
));

console.log(filtered);
```